# iOS App crashes because of -[UIView _setLayerConfig:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, uiview, crash

I am developing an iOS app (written in Swift) since weeks. Everything worked fine since a couple of hours ago. Now, at startup, I'm getting an error that occurs between the time the App Delegate `application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool` returns and the VC's `viewDidLoad()` launches

The debugger warns me `-[UIView _setLayerConfig:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` [NSException]

I've already tried to review all my properties, methods and especially the last couple of view I added before the error first appeared.

Here are the various pieces of code that (I hope) could contain the explanation :

**1. App Delegate**

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    print("Starting App Launch (App Delegate)")

    return true

}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {...}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {...}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {...}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {...}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {...}


}
```

**2. ViewController's viewDidLoad()**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()

    print("Starting App Launch (View Controller)") //Does not prints, might mean class is not even initialized

    refreshView.layer.cornerRadius = 22

    noteScrollView.delegate = self

    let fingerDragGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("dragingFinger:"))
    fingerDragGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2
    self.noteScrollView.addGestureRecognizer(fingerDragGesture)

    registerForKeyboardNotifications()

}
```

**3. Console output**

```
 'Starting App Launch (App Delegate)'

 2015-10-21 21:20:34.880 InkBook[751:98309] -[UIView _setLayerConfig:]:       unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1476873d0
```

**4. Crash Log *(Symbolicated from a crash that occurred after the previous one)***

```
Incident Identifier: A4B7E0B2-AC34-4D14-9492-A934ACA6B31F
CrashReporter Key:   08344d4a2247bd71ab8e45b3ad9a8a80390be4dc
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,1
Process:             InkBook [751]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/12A79FA4-8B45-4F3B-A489-9451461E3655/InkBook.app/InkBook
Identifier:          xyz.digital-labs.InkBook
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-10-21 21:36:51.51 +0200
Launch Time:         2015-10-21 21:20:30.30 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 9.1 (13B137)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019986bf48 objc_exception_throw + 0
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184cbfc5c __methodDescriptionForSelector + 0
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184cbcc00 ___forwarding___ + 872
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184bc0cac _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
4   UIKit                           0x000000018a7c05cc -[UIVisualEffectView _configureForEffectConfig:] + 960
5   UIKit                           0x000000018a7bfadc -[UIVisualEffectView _configureForCurrentEffect] + 116
6   UIKit                           0x000000018a7bf640 -[UIVisualEffectView initWithCoder:] + 356
7   UIKit                           0x000000018a82ffdc UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 672
8   UIKit                           0x000000018a82fd24 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 336
9   UIKit                           0x000000018a711c38 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 188
10  UIKit                           0x000000018a82ffdc UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 672
11  UIKit                           0x000000018a830154 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1048
12  UIKit                           0x000000018a82fd24 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 336
13  UIKit                           0x000000018a710f6c -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1220
14  UIKit                           0x000000018a5bc14c -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 376
15  UIKit                           0x000000018a38849c -[UIViewController loadView] + 176
16  UIKit                           0x000000018a24bd44 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 144
17  UIKit                           0x000000018a24bc9c -[UIViewController view] + 28
18  UIKit                           0x000000018a252a38 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 76
19  UIKit                           0x000000018a24ff78 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 252
20  UIKit                           0x000000018a2c58f0 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 48
21  UIKit                           0x000000018a4efcf4 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3456
22  UIKit                           0x000000018a4f3e0c -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1656
23  UIKit                           0x000000018a4f0f50 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 168
24  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018ead77c4 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 184
25  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018ead7b44 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
26  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184c70544 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
27  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184c6ffd8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
28  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184c6dcd8 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
29  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184b9cca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
30  UIKit                           0x000000018a2ba1c8 -[UIApplication _run] + 460
31  UIKit                           0x000000018a2b4ffc UIApplicationMain + 204
32  InkBook                         0x0000000100098ea4 main (AppDelegate.swift:18)
33  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019a0ba8b8 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019a1d84fc kevent_qos + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010135e328 0x101348000 + 90920
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010134bee4 0x101348000 + 16100

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019a1d7b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019a29d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019a29d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019a1d7b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019a29d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019a29d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019a1bc974 _kernelrpc_mach_vm_deallocate_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019a1bcbbc mach_vm_deallocate + 32
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x000000019a207fb4 deallocate_pages + 88
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000199886ef0 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::kill() + 72
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000199886fcc (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::tls_dealloc(void*) + 184
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019a29e1e0 _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 584
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019a29dd58 _pthread_exit + 136
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019a29d53c pthread_mutex_lock + 0
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019a29d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019a29d01c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.UIKit.KeyboardManagement
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x000000019a296648 OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64Barrier + 16
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019a29daf0 pthread_rwlock_unlock + 336
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000199877548 rwlock_tt<false>::unlockRead() + 20
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001998739f0 lookUpImpOrForward + 432
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019987ddb8 _objc_msgSend_uncached_impcache + 56
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184bbb81c -[NSMethodSignature isEqual:] + 76
6   Foundation                      0x0000000185b214dc -[NSXPCDecoder decodeInvocation] + 344
7   Foundation                      0x0000000185ce60b4 _decodeObject + 1332
8   Foundation                      0x0000000185b2080c _decodeObjectAfterSettingWhitelistForKey + 136
9   Foundation                      0x0000000185b2075c -[NSXPCDecoder decodeObjectOfClass:forKey:] + 176
10  Foundation                      0x0000000185b87658 -[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeMessageWithData:] + 312
11  Foundation                      0x0000000185b102d0 message_handler + 712
12  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000019a2d13b0 _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 68
13  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000019a2cf158 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 2132
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000101349d64 0x101348000 + 7524
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010134e2d4 0x101348000 + 25300
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010135699c 0x101348000 + 59804
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010134d334 0x101348000 + 21300
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010135699c 0x101348000 + 59804
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010134d958 0x101348000 + 22872
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000101358898 0x101348000 + 67736
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000101358590 0x101348000 + 66960
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019a29d470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019a29d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019a29d01c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x000000014756cdf0   x1: 0x000000018ac1eaa9   x2: 0x000000014756cf28   x3: 0x000000014756cf20
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x000000000000000f   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x00000001032f0d00   x9: 0x00000001032f0d08  x10: 0x00000000003ed600  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0034d6000034d600  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x00000000ffffffff  x15: 0x00000000ffffffe6
   x16: 0x000000019a29d64c  x17: 0x000000019988694c  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000014756cf20
   x20: 0x00000001476873d0  x21: 0x000000019c73e340  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x00000001a0ba4400
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x000000018ac522ec  x26: 0x0000000000000468  x27: 0x6400e034591d4c15
   x28: 0x000000019fecf000  fp: 0x000000016fdc8e50   lr: 0x0000000184cbfc5c
    sp: 0x000000016fdc8e20   pc: 0x000000019986bf48 cpsr: 0x80000000
```

**5. Assembler Output with NSException Breakpoints**

*(31) UIApplicationMain*

```
UIKit`UIApplicationMain:

0x18a2b4f30 <+0>:   stp    x24, x23, [sp, #-64]!
0x18a2b4f34 <+4>:   stp    x22, x21, [sp, #16]
0x18a2b4f38 <+8>:   stp    x20, x19, [sp, #32]
0x18a2b4f3c <+12>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #48]
0x18a2b4f40 <+16>:  add    x29, sp, #48
0x18a2b4f44 <+20>:  mov    x20, x3
0x18a2b4f48 <+24>:  mov    x21, x1
0x18a2b4f4c <+28>:  mov    x22, x0
0x18a2b4f50 <+32>:  mov    x0, x2
0x18a2b4f54 <+36>:  bl     0x191f6742c
0x18a2b4f58 <+40>:  mov    x19, x0
0x18a2b4f5c <+44>:  mov    x0, x20
0x18a2b4f60 <+48>:  bl     0x191f6742c
0x18a2b4f64 <+52>:  mov    x20, x0
0x18a2b4f68 <+56>:  adrp   x23, 92408
0x18a2b4f6c <+60>:  add    x23, x23, #4064
0x18a2b4f70 <+64>:  ldr    w8, [x23]
0x18a2b4f74 <+68>:  cbnz   w8, 0x18a2b4fa0           ; <+112>
0x18a2b4f78 <+72>:  adrp   x8, 92408
0x18a2b4f7c <+76>:  ldr    x8, [x8, #296]
0x18a2b4f80 <+80>:  cmn    x8, #1
0x18a2b4f84 <+84>:  b.eq   0x18a2b4fd4               ; <+164>
0x18a2b4f88 <+88>:  adrp   x0, 92408
0x18a2b4f8c <+92>:  add    x0, x0, #296
0x18a2b4f90 <+96>:  adrp   x1, 77361
0x18a2b4f94 <+100>: add    x1, x1, #1456
0x18a2b4f98 <+104>: bl     0x18ac191ac               ; symbol stub for: +[UIKeyboardAssistantBar sharedInstance]
0x18a2b4f9c <+108>: ldr    w8, [x23]
0x18a2b4fa0 <+112>: lsr    w8, w8, #8
0x18a2b4fa4 <+116>: cmp    w8, #513
0x18a2b4fa8 <+120>: b.lo   0x18a2b4fd4               ; <+164>
0x18a2b4fac <+124>: bl     0x191f672b8
0x18a2b4fb0 <+128>: mov    x23, x0
0x18a2b4fb4 <+132>: mov    x0, x22
0x18a2b4fb8 <+136>: mov    x1, x21
0x18a2b4fbc <+140>: mov    x2, x19
0x18a2b4fc0 <+144>: mov    x3, x20
0x18a2b4fc4 <+148>: bl     0x18a4f5110               ; _UIApplicationMainPreparations
0x18a2b4fc8 <+152>: mov    x0, x23
0x18a2b4fcc <+156>: bl     0x18ac1815c               ; symbol stub for: -[_UIActivityApplicationExtensionDiscovery .cxx_destruct]
0x18a2b4fd0 <+160>: b      0x18a2b4fe8               ; <+184>
0x18a2b4fd4 <+164>: mov    x0, x22
0x18a2b4fd8 <+168>: mov    x1, x21
0x18a2b4fdc <+172>: mov    x2, x19
0x18a2b4fe0 <+176>: mov    x3, x20
0x18a2b4fe4 <+180>: bl     0x18a4f5110               ; _UIApplicationMainPreparations
0x18a2b4fe8 <+184>: adrp   x8, 92408
0x18a2b4fec <+188>: ldr    x0, [x8, #4048]
0x18a2b4ff0 <+192>: adrp   x8, 89050
0x18a2b4ff4 <+196>: ldr    x1, [x8, #2688]
0x18a2b4ff8 <+200>: bl     0x191f67298
0x18a2b4ffc <+204>: mov    x0, x20 // Thread 1 : breakpoint 1.1
0x18a2b5000 <+208>: bl     0x191f67428
0x18a2b5004 <+212>: mov    x0, x19
0x18a2b5008 <+216>: bl     0x191f67428
0x18a2b500c <+220>: movz   w0, #0
0x18a2b5010 <+224>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #48]
0x18a2b5014 <+228>: ldp    x20, x19, [sp, #32]
0x18a2b5018 <+232>: ldp    x22, x21, [sp, #16]
0x18a2b501c <+236>: ldp    x24, x23, [sp], #64
0x18a2b5020 <+240>: ret
```

*(32) main*

```
InkBook`main:
0x100098e1c <+0>:   stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
0x100098e20 <+4>:   mov    x29, sp
0x100098e24 <+8>:   sub    sp, sp, #32
0x100098e28 <+12>:  adrp   x8, 188
0x100098e2c <+16>:  ldr    x8, [x8, #1312]
0x100098e30 <+20>:  adrp   x9, 188
0x100098e34 <+24>:  ldr    x9, [x9, #1200]
0x100098e38 <+28>:  str    w0, [x9]
0x100098e3c <+32>:  ldr    x8, [x8]
0x100098e40 <+36>:  cmn    x8, #1
0x100098e44 <+40>:  stur   w0, [x29, #-4]
0x100098e48 <+44>:  str    x1, [sp, #16]
0x100098e4c <+48>:  b.eq   0x100098e68               ; <+76> at AppDelegate.swift:18
0x100098e50 <+52>:  adrp   x8, 188
0x100098e54 <+56>:  ldr    x0, [x8, #1312]
0x100098e58 <+60>:  adrp   x8, 188
0x100098e5c <+64>:  ldr    x8, [x8, #1304]
0x100098e60 <+68>:  mov    x1, x8
0x100098e64 <+72>:  bl     0x100121714               ; symbol stub for: swift_once
0x100098e68 <+76>:  adrp   x8, 188
0x100098e6c <+80>:  ldr    x8, [x8, #1192]
0x100098e70 <+84>:  ldr    x9, [sp, #16]
0x100098e74 <+88>:  str    x9, [x8]
0x100098e78 <+92>:  bl     0x100098c68               ; type metadata accessor for InkBook.AppDelegate
0x100098e7c <+96>:  bl     0x100120544               ; symbol stub for: NSStringFromClass
0x100098e80 <+100>: movz   x8, #0
0x100098e84 <+104>: ldr    x9, [sp, #16]
0x100098e88 <+108>: ldur   w10, [x29, #-4]
0x100098e8c <+112>: str    x0, [sp, #8]
0x100098e90 <+116>: mov    x0, x10
0x100098e94 <+120>: mov    x1, x9
0x100098e98 <+124>: mov    x2, x8
0x100098e9c <+128>: ldr    x3, [sp, #8]
0x100098ea0 <+132>: bl     0x100120f4c               ; symbol stub for: UIApplicationMain
0x100098ea4 <+136>: movz   w10, #0 //Thread 1: Breakpoint 1.1
0x100098ea8 <+140>: str    w0, [sp, #4]
0x100098eac <+144>: mov    x0, x10
0x100098eb0 <+148>: mov    sp, x29
0x100098eb4 <+152>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #16
0x100098eb8 <+156>: ret
```

I hope you 'll be able to understand all these stuffs, I gave up after 6 hours fighting with AddressSanitizer, LLDB, Instruments ... #needHelpSOSME

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you have any subviews added to your `UIVisualEffectView` in your storyboard?

Comment: `UIVisualEffectView`s actually have subviews (buttons in the effects' content view), but they've been implemented from almost the beginning and any exception had been thrown because of them....

Comment: If they're in the effect view's content view then that's fine, the error message suggests that there is another unwanted view that was added outside of the content view.

Comment: Dan's comment turns out to be the correct answer… at least for me it was.

Comment: @dan's answer worked for me. I removed the `UIVisualEffectView` and then added a new one. Very strange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally fixed this issue by rebuilding the scene from scratch in Interface Builder and reconnecting the outlets manually.

i didn't remove anything from the original hierarchy, so I don't really know what made my app crash, but at least it works now ...

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. I was playing with the constraint for iPad and iPhone and after I delete some constraints they became transparently but not fully deleted. So my fix was to delete them one more time.
In this way,  I fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue (in Obj-C), was missing the `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` in the header

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue after updating the constraints for the iPad version of my App. Since it crash at start, even if I comment the entire code or uninstalled all the Views in my screen.

Finally, instead of rebuilding everything, I added a new scene and try to copy paste elements by elements to figure out what was the UiView that cause me some trouble.

Dan ask if there was a UIVisualEffectView in the storyboard and it was the case for me. So I oriented my focus on it and realise that it was that !

I deleted it completely because just uninstalled it from the scene is not enough.

Everything is fine now, I needed to rebuild only the visual effect instead of the entire scene.